# How does the json returned from a model have a field name that does not exist in the domain object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and learning it from going over this guide on their website. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

The section **Supporting changes to the API** where the name in the employee object is replaced with firstname and lastname. The json returned still has the field **name** although it's not part of the employee object anymore.

How come this property  is called 'name' and how this property gets its "name"? I understand that getName() function inside Employee class is this property's value.

Comment: You are mixing fields and properties. A field is just that a field which is part of the class a property is defined by the getter/setters available on the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping mechanism that spring is using is based on the getters and Setters, so it is taken the name of the getter to create the field named "name" in the json even though it is not present in the employee object. Instead of using traditional reflection to introspect the object and return the fields and values, is using the getter/setter approach

As it is said in the tutorial:

- Field name has been replaced by firstName and lastName.
- A "virtual" getter for the old name property, getName() is defined. It uses the firstName and lastName fields to produce a value.
- A "virtual" setter for the old name property is also defined, setName(). It parses an incoming string and stores it into the proper fields.

Comment: I did not understand it initially. Now I do, I replaced getName() with getSomething and the json name changed to "something".  Thank you so much for taking your time and explaining this to me. It helped me loads.

Comment: You are wellcome @user2792941